# Error ueAppIdToMeAppMapKey entry not found

Tags: omnet++, veins, simulte

I'm working on mec veins scenario (simultemec) , the original script has 3 UEs, I added one car ( the car have UE type) and I got this error (The simulation run for some time, and then this error have appeared) :
VirtualizationManager::stopMEApp - Error ueAppIdToMeAppMapKey entry not found!
Can you tell me how to fix it?
Thank you in advance

Comment: How can I see the error on my own computer? What software (and which versions) do I need to download? What do I have to run?

Comment: Thank you for responding, I'm using instant veins with simulte latest version, in virtual Box, I have just added a vehicle to the scenario but the simulation does not end showing the error above